# Receiving Passbook's .pkpass from URL without Webview

Tags: iphone, ios, backend, passbook

Hi first of all i have to confess i really don't understand how the whole Passbook topic really works.
So here's my situation: 
I have a backend system which creates .pkpass files stores them and creates an URL.
When i open this URL in my browser it directly starts to download the pass file.
How can i receive or open this file with my ios application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use webservices to get pass data. Webservices can send your pass data in base64(NSString) format and you decode it to get NSData.

The use the data to initiate `PKPass` Object.

```
PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:passData error:&err];
```

Once you get PKPass you can use `PKAddPassesViewController` to show it inside the app. You can find detailed explanation [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20734/beginning-passbook-part-1).

Note : you can directly download Pass data from the URL using `NSUrlConnection` and use the downloaded data to create `PKPass`.

Comment: so i can t catch it as a pkpass file, i need to receive a string and then go with the initWithData method?

Comment: Every file is a binary whether it is .pkpass or .png. You have to find a way to get file data. If you are using webservice use a base64 encoded string and decode to NSData. if you streaming directly you can get NSData. Once you get the NSData say iOS that it is really a PkPass by initiating the Object.

Comment: can i use NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:originalString]; to decode the base64 string?

Answer (score 1):

another way..simpler and can be used in mobile web apps as well. write a simple web service to return this pass download URL then parse the json/xml(depends on type of response) in your app(web or native ios) and then invoke the URL in safari.

from native app call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:passdownloadURL];

I have used it in my project and it works awesome!!

Comment: Yes i did it the same way, just had some issues how i had to send the pass data to open it the proper way....it works now but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you host the link to the PKPass item on a website you can check that the page content is really a PKPass item by looking at the mimeType property on HTTPURLResponse, which should be "application/vnd.apple.pkpass".
Once you confirm that, download the .pkpass data with an URLRequest and pass the data to the PKPass initializer like this:

```
var error:NSError?
let passBookData = PKPass( data: data, error: &error )

if error != nil
{
    print( "Error opening pkpass file" )
    return
}
let pkPassVC = PKAddPassesViewController( pass: passBookData )
currentVC.present( pkPassVC, animated: true, completion: completion )
```